# Why does Finn mistake Han's freighter for a First Order vessel?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

I could be remembering this wrong from the film... but why was Finn so convinced that the freighter Han was using to capture the falcon was the First Order? Surely, as a well trainer soldier of the First Order, he would be familiar enough with their spacecraft and would recognize a true First Order freighter when he sees one. Perhaps he is just panicking... but still.

If it is indeed an actual First Order craft, how exactly did Han manage to get it and how would he have gotten away with it? (although to me it doesn't look all that First Orderly, so I wasn't really thinking this was the case).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no explanation in the film's script, but it sounds like he simply assumed that it's the ONLY possible explanation. First Order is hunting for him (traitor) AND BB-8 (Skywalker Map). Nobody else does. So who else WOULD go through the trouble of capturing them, AND have a giant ship (`huge mouth that swallows Falcon like whale` is the expression used to show the size) capable of doing so?

```
But then: ALL THE SHIP POWER GOES OUT. BB-8 is nervous.
(CONTINUED)
CONTINUED:
FINN
... That can't be good.
REY
(heads off)
-- No it can't be --
FINN FOLLOWS REY TO:
INT. MILLENNIUM FALCON - COCKPIT - DAY
They plop into the seats, in a panic. She checks the dead
instrumentation panel:
REY
Someone's locked onto us -- all
controls are overridden.
Finn quickly, awkwardly climbs up, looks out.
REY (CONT'D)
Get off. Get off! See anything?
FINN
... Oh no.
EXT. SPACE - DAY
The Millennium Falcon, powerless, is a sitting duck.
SOMETHING EPIC appears from ABOVE: THE ANTENNA ARRAY IS THE
FIRST WE SEE OF A MASSIVE FREIGHTER, ITS GIANT HANGAR OPEN
LIKE A HUGE MOUTH WHICH SWALLOWS THE FALCON LIKE A WHALE!
INT. MILLENNIUM FALCON - COCKPIT - DAY
Finn PLOPS into his seat, horrified.
FINN
It's the First Order.
```

Comment: agree - remember - they were in the hallways of the Falcon when this occurred: no windows. It was all an assumption (and a reasonable one at that) that it was the First Order. They didn't take the time to look out the window before ducking into the maintenance pit.

Comment: @NathanK.Campbell, I'm seeing it again tonight so I can double check, but I could swear Finn made it to the cockpit to see the ship?

Comment: @DangerZone - that was my impression too - and confirmed in the script quote above. But seriously, how much can you see in a geometric situation like that? A scary cavern, that's all

Comment: @DVK - I was thinking he had more of a view of the underside of the ship. But it's definitely likely I'm misremembering and it was just the massive opening... Fascinating how the human brain just fills in details like that.

Comment: @DangerZone I'd love for you to confirm later if you remember. Agree - no telling what tricks our collective brains are playing

Comment: @NathanK.Campbell, I remembered to confirm! They make it from wherever they are in the ship to the cockpit in like 3 seconds, just enough time to see the huge cargo door opening for the Falcon. It seems likely that what DVK said is true and they simply weren't able to get a good enough read to verify whether the freighter was actually First Order or not. We get a clear enough view. Our heroes likely do not.

Comment: "it sounds like he simply assumed that it's the ONLY possible explanation" - From an out-of-universe point of view, this interpretation serves a strong purpose in the story. It establishes the paranoid panic that Finn is feeling over the possibility of being captured by the First Order, which builds to his outburst at Maz's place and his attempt to join the crew of another ship and disappear.

Comment: @recognizer - Yes, pretty much what I was trying to convey but expressed an order of magnitude better :)